# How to load plugins in Hydra when using config store and hydra.initialize()

Tags: fb-hydra

I'm having trouble figuring out how to load my plugins when using config store and hydra.initialize().

Specifically, I'm trying to load 2 plugins -- a config source plugin that allows me to load configs from GCS and a Search path plugin for GCS.

For context, my code looks something like this:

```
local_search_path = <directory_of_config>

base_config = {
    "defaults": [config_name, "_self_"],
    "hydra": {"searchpath":[local_search_path]},
}

cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="_my_app_config", node=base_config)

hydra.core.global_hydra.GlobalHydra.instance().clear()
hydra.initialize(version_base=None)

...

cfg = compose(config_name="_my_app_config", return_hydra_config=True)
```

Mentioned in the [docs](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/plugins/develop/) are 2 ways to load in plugins, both which I'm having issues with.

**Plugin registration using `Plugins.register`**

Docs mention to call The `Plugins.register` method before use with `hydra.main`, however I am not using `hydra.main`. Does anyone know if its still possible to manually register plugins given my code? I've tried registering it in multiple places with no success.

**Automatic Plugin discovery process**

I'm not entirely sure how this one works and would like some clarification. I've tried to put the `hydra_plugins` folder at the base of my repository with no success. Note I invoke my code using a Makefile which calls: `python -m foo.main`

Answer (score 0):

`hydra.initialize()` is supposed to discover plugins.
I suggest you revert to using `@hydra.main()` and make sure your plugins are discovered correctly. `@hydra.main()` offers some visibility into the discovered plugins.

You can access it via the `--info` flag. [Here](https://termbin.com/ywqi) is example output.

In particular, the first two sections are for plugins and config search path.
If you see your plugin and your config source entry.
If they are not there, your problem is not related to using `hydra.initialize()`.

```
Hydra 1.4.0.dev0
================
Installed Hydra Plugins
***********************
    ConfigSource:
    -------------
        FileConfigSource
        ImportlibResourcesConfigSource
        StructuredConfigSource
    CompletionPlugin:
    -----------------
        BashCompletion
        FishCompletion
        ZshCompletion
    Launcher:
    ---------
        BasicLauncher
    Sweeper:
    --------
        BasicSweeper

Config search path
******************
| Provider | Search path                                                                 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| hydra    | pkg://hydra.conf                                                            |
| main     | file:///home/omry/PycharmProjects/hydra/examples/patterns/multi-select/conf |
| schema   | structured://                                                               |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```